# mutex vs. lock-free when using threads for audio signal processing

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to build an Audio Spectrum Analyzer in C++. I'm trying to avoid frameworks (like e.g. JUCE), however i will use FFTW3 to calculate the FFT i need. I use WASAPI to obtain audio data.

What i've got so far:
I use WASAPI to get raw data (from the audiobuffer) of the default output device via loopback mode.
I wrote some OpenGL-code, that let's me illustrate data in different ways.

What's missing:
I still need to perform the FFT and merge everything together.

What my problem is:
I'm not sure how to handle thread communication, or more on how to deal with thread-safety in this application. My idea for the setup is this: I use a FIFO-queue with fixed length (circular buffer?) and fill it with given WASAPI data whenever it's ready (Thread 1). Then have another Thread (Thread 2) to read the queue and to perform the FFT. Frequencies are stored in an array and drawn via another thread, that runs the OpenGL-Code (Thread 3).

Does it make sense to use lock-free implementations of a fifo-queue and array or should i use mutexes to guarantee thread-safety? Would it make sense to lock while performing read/write operations to said datastructures and then blocking Thread 2 and 3 while no data is available?

I'm sorry if this is trivial to you, but i'm kind of new to multithreading.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Minimise shared state as much as possible - also be aware of "false sharing" - try to keep different threads operating on different parts of memory.  To that end use 64-byte alignment on buffers.  Use mutexes at first, then look to optimise later.

Comment: Would you suggest to merge thread 2 and 3 (process and draw in a single thread) to sacrifice performance for thread-safety at first?

Comment: I would suggest that you measure performance for such decision...

Comment: Lock free only make sense if threads send/receive a lot of data or spin wait for incoming data. Spin waiting data results in a lower latency but IDK if this important here. The main problem of spin waits is that they consume a lot of CPU resources for nothing so one should not use them if possible. When a lot of data are transferred, there are ways to make this fast with mutexes though it requires to design the application more carefully. Note that accessing data from different code is not great for caches and can be expensive on NUMA platforms (like AMD on processors). Details are missing.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.
@JérômeRichard Sounds good at first. The processing should be done in real-time (or well, asap for that matter). so i guess spin wait would make sense, so i will have a look at all the discussed scenerios and measure performance.

Comment: @xKiba Note that the low latency has a cost: it often reduce the throughput. This means that the whole computation can be slower because of that. This is certainly the case here: the spin lock cause huge context switch issues if the number of core is smaller than the number of thread, and it also cause multiple core to have a high frequency which in turn causes the turbo frequency not to be enabled for core that need to make the actual computation. Spin lock/waits are considered as often a bad idea and strongly discouraged by experts (eg. Linus Torvalds). Please think twice before using them.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks. Currently i think i don't need spin locks or waits, since i only want a spsc way to buffer the audio loopback data and then later the processed fft-data

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that this is all for music visualisation and not for precise realt-time frequency measuring. So i don't really care about squeezing the last bit of performance as long as all 3 computations ("sample", process, draw) are done at least 30 times a second -> 30 fps